# Настройки Magento

Tags: php, cms, magento

Создал блок. Нужно сделать в админке настройку (checkbox) например Show Images
И использовать настройку в блоке.

Magento 1.9

Я только 2 день как пробую magento! Никак не разберусь как добавить пункт в Система > Конфигурация. и как потом с ним работать!

Comment: куда хоть копать... не могу нигде найти....

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы добавить поле в админку в системные настройки например нужно:

1. Добавить в модуль system.xml
2. В него добавить секцию/группу/поле например каталог/моя настройка/название настроки
3. Получить значение Mage::getStoreConfig('секция/группа/поле',Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())

Вот неплохой [ресурс](http://freaksidea.com/php_and_somethings/show-60-magento-konfighuratsiia-ot-a-do-ia-system-xml) с подробным объяснением.

Еще совет всегда смотреть в ядро системы, там много всего интересного)

---

Нашел еще новый способ(пока не испробовал) для поля можно указывать `frontend_model` и она наследует класс `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Renderer_Interface` и там есть уже много реализованных классов http://joxi.ru/Vrw3goguOJzW0r так что я думаю вполне можно и чекбокс и все что угодно добавить используя это метод.

Answer (score 0):

Магента не позволяет в system / configuration юзать чекбоксы (если об этом идет речь). Сделайте через yes/no (гляньте по аналогии как делается)

Comment: Не важен тип... куда все записать? Добавил значение своего конфига в базу - работает, но в админке не отображается.. Писать нужно в xml или БД

Comment: Гляньте тут http://freaksidea.com/php_and_somethings/show-60-magento-konfighuratsiia-ot-a-do-ia-system-xml